# Silverlight Data problem

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have the following code, which compiles but doesn't bring back any data.  Here is my point where I assign the data to the grid.  The context has data in, but the grid displays nothing.  Any ideas?

```
// Load the Events
this.eventsDataGrid.ItemSource = this.context.SalesActions;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be ItemsSource and not ItemSource :)

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: Man, I can't believe that an S can cause so much grief.  Thanks!